# OpenCV 2.4.13.4 Make Error with Mingw64-GCC-5.1

Tags: opencv, build, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile `OpenCV 2.4.13.4` with `Mingw64-GCC-5.1` on `Windows 10`but I keep receiving the following error:

```
[ 95%] Generating perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wo-array-bounds'
modules\stitching\CMakeFiles\pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:6569: recipe for target 'modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching.dir/all] Error 2
```

Please note that there is no typo here, `-Wo-array-bounds` is exactly the output I receive ( and not `-Wno-array-bounds` that google search suggests!). Any idea how to solve the problem? I searched for `-Wo-array-bounds` in the entire build folder to possibly change it to `-Wno-array-bounds` but I couldn't find this command line option in any file located in the build folder.